# Oracle APEX 4.2 Set value of dropdown menu to default

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm using Application Express 4.2.0.00.27

Was trying to set a default value in a drop down menu so that when the user access the page it can load some data

Now I know that I can do this using the default section while editing  the drop down item or using a computation

The problem is that I need the drop down to display something and return something else

The LOV populating the dropdown is as per following:

ItemA   1
ItemB   2
....and so on

How could I set perhaps "1" as a default return value while displaying ItemA ?

Thank you !

Comment: There's a specific field on the lov item definition that let you enter a default value.

Comment: Question is unclear. You say you know about setting the default value, yet you don't know how to set the default value? What are we missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You can always define a pair of values where the first one will be displayed and the second one will be returned as the selected value.

**Example 1**: List of values based on SQL query

```
SELECT ename, empno FROM emp ORDER by 1 
//Here ename will be displayed and empno will be returned
```

**Example 2**: List of values with same display and return value

```
SELECT ename d, ename r FROM emp ORDER BY 1

//When selecting the same column for both the display and return values use a column alias.
```

**Example 3**: Static list examples

```
•STATIC:Cow,Dog,Cat,Lion (will be sorted alphabetically)

•STATIC2:10,15,20,25,50,100,200,500,1000,10000 (sorted in order of creation)

•STATIC:Yes;Y,No;N (show Yes / No, return Y and N)
```

**Example 4**: List of values with bind variable

```
SELECT ENAME, EMPNO FROM EMP WHERE DEPTNO = :P3_DEPTNO ORDER by 1
```